# How to find home range using kernel density estimation in QGIS

Tags: area, density

I am trying to find the home range for a group of animals with a few hundred data points. My teacher has said that I should try and use 50% and 95% estimates for a Kernel Density analysis. I have seen a lot of people describing how to use a heat map, which I have created in QGIS, (except for the fact I'm still unsure what I should input as a radius). Although I understand the darkest central colour is the core area with the slightly lighter being home range, I do not understand where the actual home range area estimate would be found from this analysis.

This is what I've created so far with 100 m radius.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure we can give a final answer here with the information you provided. You should probably better ask your teacher about what they mean and expect.

Comment: Its an independent project so unfortunately they wont provide any more guidance. I'm just wondering where you get the range area from in the process, and how to specify the 50% and 95% densities when setting parameters. Is the heat map just a visualization or do you get the actual area from this?